# Point DNS to Subdirectory on AWS

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How do you point the DNS to go to a subdirectory on AWS hosting?
Right now my folder is this:

```
/var/www/html/sites/mysite
```

When I visit the domain, it's going to www.mydomain.com/sites/mysite
And I want it to be just the domain name.

It's an Apache server that I'm using.

Comment: You need to configure that as the root directory of your Apache server. Or move the contents from `mysite` directly int `/var/www/html`. DNS only points a domain name to a server, it does not deal with paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure your Apache to either use that folder for the default root directory, or setup virtual hosts for that directory.